# AWS API Gateway Method Test: Error Authorization not configured

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I've created a RESTful API on AWS and I'm trying to test the POST method. I give a sample request to the the request body in the api gatemway console's test interface it get this response:

```
{
  "Error": "Authorization not configured",
  "Reference": "e6b7ec86-97fe-11e7-b480-ebefe7f11420"
}
```

I originally had this set to a Cognito User Pool with read/write access to a corresponding table, but I got this error message. I tried removing authorization in the method just to test this, but again I received this error.

As far as I can tell, I have authorization set up across the board.

- IAM role created to add, update, query, and delete, from table (`trusted entities: AWS service: lambda`) and the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`
- Lambda function using an existing (above) role
- authorizer created using my User Pool for authorization
- resource and method (POST) created using cognito user pool authorizer from above

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but everything seems to be in order as I step through it here. Any help is much appreciated and please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: Did you try adding the API Gateway as one of the Lambda function triggers?

Answer (score 20):

I found this question linked from the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=264308) The OP there and I both ran into this same problem while going through the Wild Rydes tutorial.

I was able to solve this problem by:

1. In the API's settings under "Resources", click on the "POST" method, then click on "Method Request".

[image]

2. In the Method Request settings, click the edit icon for "Authorization"

[image]

3. Choose the Cognito pool.

[image]

4. Click the check icon to save the change

[image]

Once the change is made, the method request should no longer say None for auth

[image]

5. Redeploy the API.

[image]

Comment: Nice, I forgot to redeploy the API after changing the Auth property.

Comment: I forgot to click on the confirm button, but now it works! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is having this problem, I simply had to clear my cached data on my browser for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out after looking through the WildRydes tutorial and Lambda Test. I needed to set the `Authorization` header to the current user's JWT token. I did this with the following function:

```
getCurrentAuthToken: function (userPool) {
  return new Promise(function fetchCurrentAuthToken (resolve, reject) 
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser()

    if (cognitoUser) {
      cognitoUser
        .getSession(function sessionCallback (err, session) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else if (!session.isValid()) {
            resolve(null)
          } else {
            resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken())
          }
        })
    } else {
      resolve(null)
    }
  })
}
```

and use the returned value of the promise to set the `Authorization` header in my request.

Comment: Where I need to put that function?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the German version of this tutorial and they translated the value of the token source too, which is wrong at this point.
I just had to change the token source in the API Gateway to the English phrase `Authorization` and deploy the API again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues until I [set the Auth to none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9S2l.png) in the OPTIONS Method Request.

Select OPTIONS on the left then click Method Request. Make sure [Authorization is set to NONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il7eR.png). Remember to deploy the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly confirm where we need to put the below code.

getCurrentAuthToken: function (userPool) {
return new Promise(function fetchCurrentAuthToken (resolve, reject)
let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser()

```
if (cognitoUser) {
  cognitoUser
    .getSession(function sessionCallback (err, session) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else if (!session.isValid()) {
        resolve(null)
      } else {
        resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken())
      }
    })
} else {
  resolve(null)
}
```

})
}